# heavy Drupal 7 site performance issue

Tags: php, nginx, drupal, memcached

I am running a drupal 7 website on a Linux server (with 4 cores and 12GB RAM) with LEMP (nginx+php5-fpm+mysql).
The drupal installation has a large number of modules enabled(all of which are needed).
I also use apc + boost + memcache + authcache for caching. The caching seems to be working (i see pages being served from cache)
and the site has a reasonable response time.
I have run stress tests with the website running in a url like www-1.example.com. (www-1.example.com points to the ip of my webserver, let's say x.x.x.x) 
and the results are fine (for up to 100 concurrent users)
The problem starts when I change the dns so that www.example.com also points to x.x.x.x. Then the cpu of my webserver (all 4 cores) reach 100% at short time.
I have been expereimenting with the following parameters on the www.conf file with no luck:

```
Configuration 1:
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_requests = 200
```

result: 100% cpu usage, low memory usage

Configuration final:

```
pm.max_children = 300
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_requests = 200
```

result: low cpu usage, 100% memory usage

Can anyone guide me to find the optimal comfiguration or has any idea on what can cause the 100% cpu usage?
How do i culculate the maximum number of concurrent usages that can run without problem based on server parameters?

Comment: do you have pm = dynamic?

Comment: Server configurations are considered off-topic on SO, however you might find help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Yes, i do have pm=dynamic